# 'Event' object has no attribute 'controller' - Function can't access parameters of class as Event object

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Right now I need one class (`GraphPage`) to access parameters of others (`StartPage`) once entries has been input. So I've binded `update` function in `GraphPage` to an Event in `StartPage`. However, the update function needs to access the `controller` for both frames to get the entries input. But now update function is treated as an Event and can't access any attributes of its class. How do I make this work?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from lmfit.models import ExponentialGaussianModel
from lmfit import Parameters
from tkinter import messagebox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import loadtxt
import math

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class PeakFitting(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, GraphPage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]

        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, classname):
        '''Returns an instance of a page given it's class name as a string'''
        for page in self.frames.values():
            if str(page.__class__.__name__) == classname:
                return page
        return None

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

       # Setting up frame and widget
        label_iso = tk.Label(self, text="Isotope A, Element (ex: 133,Cs)"
        label_iso.grid(row=4, column=0)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry1.grid(row=4, column=1)

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph Page",
                     command=lambda: controller.show_frame(GraphPage))
        self.button3.bind("<Button-1>", GraphPage.update)
        button3.grid(row=7, columnspan=2)

class GraphPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.a = fig.add_subplot()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        startpage = self.controller.get_page("StartPage")


    def update(self):

        startpage = self.controller.get_page("StartPage")
        self.iso = startpage.entry1.get()

##Calculation code for analysis not needed for question

app = PeakFitting()
app.mainloop()
```

Error 'Event' object has no attribute 'controller' is at first line of `update` function in `GraphPage`

Thank you!!!

Comment: There's far too much code here. Please cut it down to the minimum needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Done! I'm sorry for the long code >.<

Comment: don't name a function `update` if that function inherits from a widget; tkinter widgets have a built-in method named `update`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've changed the name to calculate. That did not solve the problem though... Do you have any suggestions on how else should I get entry inputs from one frame to another? Thank you!!!

Comment: Add in a few try-except blocks to figure out what line or part of code is throwing this exception. This won't just help you, but everyone looking at the code.
`try:
    pass
except:
    pass`